# Message "can't parse JSON. Raw result:" added to response body

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to define a file download endpoint using the OpenAPI spec (v3).  I am facing two problems.
1) the file is not being downloaded
2) within swagger-ui, the response body shows a message that isn't produced by the server (i.e. can't parse JSON. Raw result:"

Anyone have a clue as to what I am doing wrong?

YAML code snapshot:
[image]

Output result from swagger-ui running on an AWS server.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a UI problem. Open an issue in the Swagger UI repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues.

Comment: GitHub issue #4098 created.

Answer (score 7):

The cause of the anomalous message, I was told, is because application/json is the content media said to be returned in the server's response header. See the header here:
[image]

The response is actually a text file -- not JSON. The sending server is incorrectly configured. Swagger-UI runtime response handler determines whether the response is valid.  So Swagger-UI outputs the "can't parse JSON..." message.

Because of the error, the output to local storage function on the browser is not performed.

For more details, refer to the Swagger-UI issue [#4098](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4098).

Comment: A simple string is a valid json, you can verify it here https://jsonlint.com.
So swagger should be able to parse such a response, that is a String with content-type application/json.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   services.AddMvc(config => {
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
          .AddJsonOptions(options => {
              options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ";
              options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
              options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
              options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
          });
```